# Returning the value inside .then()

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, express

Using Google's api I'm able to get places nearby printed to the console

```js
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
 // Find places nearby
      googleMapsClient.placesNearby({
          language: 'en',
          location: [-33.865, 151.038],
          radius: 500,
          type: 'restaurant'
        })
        .asPromise()
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.json.results);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

I want to send the response which has all the places nearby to the client so I can print them in a table using pug.

I'm having trouble sending that data, when I try `res.send(response.json.results`

I get `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: There's no such thing as `response.send()` in your code, only `res.send()`. Please take 30 seconds to re-read your code and edit your question if you still have a problem.

Comment: Wrong. the response comes from Google's. and res from express route.

Comment: Check ` .then((response) => {`

Comment: I'm glad you edited, but your previous post was mentioning `TypeError: response.send is not a function`, to which I said response.send() can't be a thing ;)

Comment: Can you add back res.send(response.json.results) exactly how you are attempting?

Comment: The code you have provided will not throw the error you have indicated. You left out something important. at least two somethings.

Answer (score 0):

Following the express documentation, https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res ,you could do:

```
.then(response => {
   res.send(response).
})
```

or

```
.then(response => {
  res.json(response)
})
```

Just check if you have to use .asPromise() before then.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {

      let response = await googleMapsClient.placesNearby({
          language: 'en',
          location: [-33.865, 151.038],
          radius: 500,
          type: 'restaurant'
        })
        .asPromise()
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      console.log(response.json.results);
      return res.send(response.json.results)

});
```

[Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)